# Mostrar un Árbol Binario (IN-Post-Pre)

Tags: java, árboles-binarios

Ya hice el árbol binario y la función para agregar los nodos, e inclusive para mostrarlos por consola y  todo funciona bien: se muestran  en el orden correcto.

Pero lo que no logro hacer es que se muestren en la parte de la interfase todo según la opción que seleccione. Solo se llega a mostrar la raíz del árbol

Este es el código del Árbol

```
public class BinaryTree {


    Nodo root;


    public String  addNode(int key, String name){
        String Linea="";
        Nodo  newNodo = new Nodo(key, name);

            if(root == null){
                root= newNodo;
               // System.out.println("el nuevo nodo a sido agragado como Raiz");
               Linea="El nuevo nodo a sdo agregado como Raiz";
              } else {
                    Nodo focusNodo = root;
                    Nodo parent;
                        while(true){
                                parent = focusNodo;
                                    if(key < focusNodo.key){

                                        focusNodo = focusNodo.LftChild;

                                            if(focusNodo == null){
                                            parent.LftChild = newNodo;
                                              // System.out.println("Nuevo nodo  a sido agregado como Hoja izquierda ");
                                              Linea="Nuevo nodo  sido agregado como hoja izquierda de :" + parent.name;
                                            break;
                                            }

                                    }else{
                                        focusNodo = focusNodo.RgtChild;
                                            if(focusNodo == null){

                                                parent.RgtChild = newNodo;
                                                //System.out.println("Nuevo nodo asido agregado como Hoja derecha");
                                                Linea="Nuevo nodo a sido agregado como Hoja derecha de : " + parent.name;
                                                break;


                                            }


                                    }

                        }

            }
            return Linea;

     }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////Fin Addnode//////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////InOrder////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void InOrderTraverseTree(Nodo focusNodo){

            if(focusNodo != null){

            InOrderTraverseTree(focusNodo.LftChild);
            System.out.println(focusNodo);
            InOrderTraverseTree(focusNodo.RgtChild);

            }

    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////inorder end/////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////preorden////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////

    public String  PreOrderTraverseTree(Nodo focusNodo){
        String ND= "";

            if(focusNodo != null){

            ND=String.valueOf(focusNodo);   
            //System.out.println(focusNodo + "10");   
            PreOrderTraverseTree(focusNodo.LftChild);
            PreOrderTraverseTree(focusNodo.RgtChild);
            }

            return ND;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////preorder end/////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////postorden////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void PostOrderTraverseTree(Nodo focusNodo){
            if(focusNodo != null){

            PostOrderTraverseTree(focusNodo.LftChild);
            PostOrderTraverseTree(focusNodo.RgtChild);
            System.out.println(focusNodo + "20");
            }

    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////postorder end/////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////Main//////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                BinaryTree TheTree = new BinaryTree();

                TheTree.addNode(50, "Boss");
                TheTree.addNode(25, "UnderBoss");
                TheTree.addNode(30, "OfficeManager");
                TheTree.addNode(90, "Secretary");
                TheTree.addNode(75, "Salesman");


                System.out.println("****************/n");
                TheTree.InOrderTraverseTree(TheTree.root);
                System.out.println("****************/n");
                TheTree.PreOrderTraverseTree(TheTree.root);
                System.out.println("****************/n");
                TheTree.PostOrderTraverseTree(TheTree.root);

            }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
            /////////////end main///////////////////////
            ///////////////////////////////////////////
    } 

       ///            Nodo estructura// 

    class Nodo {
    int key;
    String name;
    Nodo LftChild;
    Nodo RgtChild;


    Nodo(int key, String name){
        this.key=key;
        this.name=name;        
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////
     public String toString(){
       String ND;
        ND= name + " has a key of : " +key + "/18";

    return ND; 
    }    
}
```

Y este es el del combobox que estoy utilizando:

```
private void CombosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  
    Object option = Combos.getSelectedItem();
    String ND="";

    if (option.equals("PreOrden")){            
        ND=TheTree.PreOrderTraverseTree(TheTree.root);                                  
        ListTXT.setText(ND + "\n"); 
    }     

    if(option.equals("InOrden")){           
        TheTree.InOrderTraverseTree(TheTree.root);
        ListTXT.setText(ND);
    }

    if(option.equals("PostOrden")){
        TheTree.PostOrderTraverseTree(TheTree.root);
        ListTXT.setText(ND);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entiendo bien tu problema, el combobox tan sólo muestra la raíz del árbol. El problema está en la manera en la que almacenas los resultados al recorrer el árbol. En el recorrido PreOrden devuelves un String, pero este string es tan sólo el valor del primer nodo, ya que los demás valores provenientes de la recursión no son asignados a ninguna variable o utilizados en ningún caso. En los recorridos InOrden y PostOrden si que imprimes desde la función el valor de los nodos, sin embargo no retornas nada, por lo que la asignación al string ND no sirve.
Deberías devolver un string de cada función para poder asignarla al TextBox. Como ejemplo te pongo la función InOrden:

```
public String InOrderTraverseTree(Nodo focusNodo){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if(focusNodo != null){

        sb.append(InOrderTraverseTree(focusNodo.LftChild)).append(" ");
        sb.append(focusNodo.name).append(" ");
        sb.append(InOrderTraverseTree(focusNodo.RgtChild)).append(" ");
        }
        return sb.toString();


}
```

Comment: Gracias entendí perfectamente lo que me faltaba ....Me funciono perfectamente...

Comment: @AlexanderVargas recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que la pregunta se cierre. Saludos!